# Redirect logs of another program to my Tkinter program

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, logging, tkinter

My aim is to show the logs of another program (its code is not mine) to my Tkinter GUI. I already ran the another program using subprocess after my GUI accepted an input for it, but its output is showing in the command prompt.

How do you access the getLogger from the another program (in another folder) and redirect it to my Text widget? Any clues or tips for me to be clarified will be a great help!

This is some of the snippets though. The ResultsInterface is a toplevel window from the gui accepting inputs, and called after pressing the main gui's Run button. I plan to call the subprocess(['python', 'program.py'] + input) and display it on the text widget.

```
class IODirector(object):
    def __init__(self, text_area):
        self.text_area = text_area

class StdoutDirector(IODirector):
    def write(self, msg):
        self.text_area.insert(END, msg)
    def flush(self):
        pass

class ResultsInterface():
  def __init__(self, master, word = ""):
    self.master = master
    self.word = word
    self.frame = Frame(self.master)
    self.master.title("Results")
    self.text_area = Text(master, borderwidth = 3, width = 80, height = 20, font = "Consolas 11", relief="sunken")
    self.text_area.grid(row = 4, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky ="we")
    self.do_run
    self.frame.grid()

  def do_run(self):
    t = Thread(target=run_thug)
    sys.stdout = StdoutDirector(self.text_area)
    # configure the nameless "root" logger to also write         
    # to the redirected sys.stdout
    #Just saw this snippet in other's answer, how do I show logs only to the Text text_area widget                         
    logger = logging.getLogger("Program")                                   
    console = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)             
    logger.addHandler(console)
    #t.start() #want it to run with the log appearing on my text_area

  def run_thug(self): 
    input_args = "/path/to/program.py" + " " + self.word
    cmdr = ['python']+(input_args.split(' '))
    self.process = Popen((cmdr), stdout=PIPE)
```